Prove that this integral is equal to $z^2$ WITHOUT using Cauchy's integral formula
I have the following integral which I obtained from plugging in $f(z)=z^2$ and curve
C parametrized by $s(t)=e^{it}$ to Cauchy's integral formula:
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{e^{3i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}-z}}d\theta$
How can I prove that it is in fact equal to $z^2$ without using said formula. I've managed to get the indefinite integral being equal to $\frac{u^2/2+2uz+z^2\int\frac{du}{u} }{2\pi i} + C$, with $u=e^{i\theta}-z$. Where should I go from here?

You can evaluate $\int_C \frac{du}u$ directly, so I'm totally confused by your post(s).
$$\int_{|u|=1}\frac{du}u = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} i\,d\theta = 2\pi i.$$

Oops, I'm a dumbass, sorry, I thought something like that might have been possible. I'm new to complex analysis if you can't tell haha

Yeah, for such problems you can basically reduce the standard Cauchy integral formula applications to this single fact by (sometimes tricky) application of partial fractions. You can find plenty of such questions on this site. Anyhow, if you don't have follow-up issues, you should accept the answer. :)

Ah, one question, as I'm doing indefinite integrals, how does that work. Surely the limits of integration are going to be weird due to the substitution? Also, I can't accept the answer for another minute, I'm trying haha.

The substitution is not valid unless you restrict to $[0,2\pi-\epsilon]$, which you can of course do. Then take the limit at the end. However, I still recommend that you do the partial fractions decomposition of $\dfrac{\zeta^2}{\zeta-z}$ and then you'll understand much more clearly. In this case, it's just polynomial division (because there is only the single pole).

Okay, thanks! I'll have a look both ways.

The issue with taking the limit as epsilon goes to 0 is that it ends up with the whole thing being 0, which does make sense, but yeah, PFD seems the most  sensible

The whole thing except the $\int du/u$ term, yes.

Doesn't the $\int du/u$ term turn into the limit as  epsilon goes to 0 of $iz^2(e^{i(2\pi-\epsilon)}-1)$? Also, how do I actually perform PFD on something with an already linear denominator?

That term you have to do as I answered originally. And, as I said, part of the partial fraction decomposition algorithm is to do long division when the degree of the numerator is not less than the degree of the denominator.
